# php script stops in the middle with no errors

Tags: php, loops

I got script that iterate all images in directory and resize them.
I got directory with 2000 images which takes some time.

I ran the script and saw that it resized only 40-50 images, then I ran it again, it resized ANOTHER 40-50 images and so on...

Do you have any idea why this is happening and how to allow the script run until it really done?

Comment: What is your time limit set to in your php settings?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: max_execution_time = 30, Timeouts Connection: 300 - Keep-Alive: 15

Comment: Did it run about 30 seconds then stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter a maximum execution time limit

if you are running a script that needs to execute for unknown time, or forever.. you may use

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 1):

On that page of code add: `set_time_limit(0);` should run until it is done.